# NP-Completeness and NP

Tags: np-complete, open-problem

Given : 
$S$ is an $NP-Complete$ problem
$Q$ and $R$ are two other problems not known to be in $NP$.
$Q$ is polynomial-time reducible to $S$ and $S$ is polynomial-time reducible to $R$.

My thoughts so far-
For $Q$ to be $NP-Complete$, by formal definitions, $Q$ must be in $NP$ and all other problems in $NP$ must be reducible to $Q$ in polynomial-time.
1. How to prove that $Q$ is in $NP$? 
 
2. Is $R$ in $NP-hard$?

Comment: $Q$ will not be NP complete in general. As every problem in $P$ is polynomial time reducible to everything, we know that in particular it is polynomial time reducible to $S$.

Comment: My book has given four options to select from - 1)$R$ is $NP-Complete$ 2)$R$ is $NP-Hard$ 3)$Q$ is $NP-Complete$ 4)$Q$ is $NP-Hard$ and the answer is "$Q is NP-Complete$".
Please explain me the answer.

Comment: "Is n = 0" is trivially polynomial-time reducible to anything, including S. So there is nothing we can say about Q except that it is in NP. Since S is polynomial-time reducible to R, R must be NP-hard. We have no reason to say that R is in NP, so we don't know that it is NP-complete.

Comment: The only thing that must by true is $2)$. Let $T$ be a problem in $NP$, then by hypothesis there is a polynomial time reduction $r_1$ to $S$ (as $S$ is NP-complete). As $S$ is polynomial time reducible to $R$ then there is a reduction $r_2$ witnessing this fact. So then the reduction "do $r_1$ then $r_2$" is polynomial time and reduces $T$ to $R$. Hence $R$ is NP-hard.

Comment: @James: If I made a slight change in the question saying that $R$ is known to be in $NP$ then can we safely say that $R$ is $NP-Complete$?

Comment: If $R$ is NP hard and also in NP then it is NP-complete, as that is the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of what the definitions of "NP", "NP-complete" and "NP-hard" mean.

NP means: Easy enough to be solved in polynomial time by a non-deterministic computer.

NP-hard means: Hard enough so that every problem in NP can be solved by converting it to our problem in polynomial time, solving the problem, and converting the solution back in polynomial time. "x is NP-hard" <=> "Every problem y in NP is polynomial time reducible to x".

NP-complete means: Easy enough to be in NP, but hard enough to be NP-hard. "x is NP-complete" <=> "x is in NP and x is NP-hard".

Actually, you can now answer the question without any understanding what NP, NP-complete and so on mean, just from the definitions of NP-hard and NP-complete.